# Break down article using App Script In Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using the App Script, I need to break down article:
In the first column this one would be whatever the H1 is, in the second column whatever the first H2 is, in the next column all the paragraphs are going underneath it, then in next whatever the second H2 is, all the paragraphs are going underneath that one and so on up until it gets to the seventh H2 and the remain. And then at that point, I wanted just to dump the rest of the article into it. So, like for an article where we may have multiple H2 or more than seven, it would just put everything else in that last column.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13uI-7e-iaeHW4G86wo5UQ5lbmXXHofNvKmZcz27mqCM/edit#gid=0) is the sheet that have sample and data.

Comment: When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, "Output" columns have "Blog Title" column. But, in your sample input values, I cannot find a value related to "Blog Title". In your question, is "Blog Title" different from your current question? If you have other patterns of sample input values that you have never shown, can you provide them and your expected values? First, I would like to correctly understand your question. I apologize for this.

Comment: Thank you so much. Ignore the "Blog Title" Column. That's different. Patterns will be similar to the sample I have added to the Spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your following reply,

> Ignore the "Blog Title" Column. That's different. Patterns will be similar to the sample I have added to the Spreadsheet.

In your question, I understood your goal is as follows.

- You want to achieve the following situation using Google Apps Script.

[image]

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and set your sheet name.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("A3:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const temp1 = range.getValues().map(([a]) =>
    a.split("\n").reduce((o, e, i, a) => {
      if (e) {
        let tag = e.match(/^<(.*?)>/)[1].toUpperCase();
        if (tag != "P") {
          if (o.temp.length > 0) {
            o.res.push(o.temp);
            o.temp = [];
          }
          o.res.push([e]);
        } else if (i == a.length - 1) {
          if (tag == "P") {
            o.temp.push(e);
            o.res.push(o.temp);
          } else {
            o.res.push([e]);
          }
        } else {
          o.temp.push(e);
        }
      }
      return o;
    }, { res: [], temp: [] }).res
  ).map(e => e.map(f => f.join("\n")));
  const maxLen = Math.max(...temp1.map(r => r.length));
  const values = temp1.map(r => [...r, ...Array(maxLen - r.length).fill(null)]);
  range.offset(0, 2, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run to your sample Spreadsheet, the above situation is obtained.

#### Note:

- This script is for your sample Spreadsheet. When you change the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working on the sample. But when I pasted the original Article, the script gave errors. [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E7I4dq1gfbNsHoIJ91WyQbizGwao5fYhoiRtEvOWQ5w/edit#gid=0) new spreadsheet in which I have pasted the original article. Please check. Thank you

Comment: @user8702720 Thank you for replying. From `Thank you so much. It is working on the sample.`, I understood your issue was resolved. About your new issue of `But when I pasted the original Article, the script gave errors. here new spreadsheet in which I have pasted the original article. Please check. Thank you`, I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working now. But there is a simple issue. Upon receiving Seventh H2, I want to dump the rest of the article into a column. For now, upon receiving the seventh H2 Script is putting in separate columns. Thank you

Comment: @user8702720 Thank you for replying. About `Thank you so much. It is working now.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @user8702720 About your new question of `But there is a simple issue.`, I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Thank you for replying. yes, sure. I have posted a new question. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75703250/fix-the-article-format-using-app-script-in-google-sheet) is the link to it. Thank you so much

Comment: @user8702720 Thank you for your response. I will check your new question. When I have questions, I will ask them. And when I found the answer, I would like to post it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252454/discussion-between-user8702720-and-tanaike).