# Fix the article format using app script in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using the App Script, I need to break down the article:

What I completed:

In the first column this one would be whatever the H1 is, in the second column whatever the first H2 is, in the next column all the paragraphs are going underneath it, then in next whatever the second H2 is, all the paragraphs are going underneath that one.

What to be completed:

So on up until it gets to the seventh H2 and the remaining. And then at that point, I wanted just to dump the rest of the article into the last column. So, like for an article where we may have multiple H2 or more than seven, it would just put everything else in that last column.

Upon receiving Seventh H2, I want to dump the rest of the article into a column. For now, upon receiving the seventh H2 Script is putting in separate columns. As you can see in the attached image.
[image]

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Emgcacro_Lsu2zoVvvumLd9HnhVTWYE0uny6ZpHVajs/edit#gid=0) is the sheet that has the script and data.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your input and output values you expect from your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question. I apologize for this.

Comment: _Here is the sheet that has the script and data._ Please do not expect that users will/must/can/should open your spreadsheet to view your data or your script. Your question needs to stand on its own - the details and layout of your data should be included in your question. Also, your script should be included (in text form) in the body of your question.

Comment: _Fix the article format_ There is no "article format" in Google sheets. You have mentioned "H1" but this seems to be a reference to HTML. With the greatest respect, you have not explained your scenario, your data, the nature of an "article", nor EXACTLY what is your problem. Would you please edit your question to this information.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your reply. I have updated the spreadsheet. I have highlighted in blue color what I want as output (Row 3). And Highlighted in Orange color what script currently gave as output (Row 4). I hope It make sense now. Apologize for my poor english.

Comment: @Tedinoz apologize for this. Sure, I will edit my question. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to summarize all lines after the tag of "H2" is existing 6 times.

In this case, how about modifying your script as follows? I found your current script in your provided Spreadsheet.

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("A3:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const temp1 = range.getValues().map(([a]) =>
    a.split("\n").reduce((o, e, i, a) => {
      if (e) {
        let tag = e.match(/^<(.*?)>/)[1].toUpperCase();
        if (tag != "P") {
          if (o.temp.length > 0) {
            o.res.push(o.temp);
            o.temp = [];
          }
          o.res.push([e]);
        } else if (i == a.length - 1) {
          if (tag == "P") {
            o.temp.push(e);
            o.res.push(o.temp);
          } else {
            o.res.push([e]);
          }
        } else {
          o.temp.push(e);
        }
      }
      return o;
    }, { res: [], temp: [] }).res
  ).map(e => e.map(f => f.join("\n")));
  const maxLen = Math.max(...temp1.map(r => r.length));

  // I modified below script.
  const values = temp1.map(r => [...r, ...Array(maxLen - r.length).fill(null)]);
  const res = values.map(r => {
    let n = 0;
    const idx = r.map(e => e.toUpperCase().includes("H2") ? ++n : 0).indexOf(7);
    return [...r.splice(0, idx), r.join("\n")];
  });
  range.offset(0, 2, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

- From your expected situation, in this modification, I modified the converted value for achieving your goal.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working but when I put my other articles it gives me this error. `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'match')
(anonymous) @ Code.gs:44
(anonymous) @ Code.gs:43
myFunction @ Code.gs:41`
[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FzWmcXQRyu25V4mdXQPVvafX4X5sUUODzEJ4xUywVPc/edit#gid=0) is the spreadsheet in which I have added the articles. Please check. Thank you

Comment: Also, the script is missing the last paragraphs of the article in the last column where we summarize all lines after the tag of "H2" is existing 6 times.

Comment: @user8702720 Thank you for replying. From `Thank you so much. It is working`, I understood that your issue was resolved.

Comment: @user8702720 About your new question of `when I put my other articles it gives me this error. TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'match')`, I would like to support you. But, my answer is to your initial question. Because I prepared it using your provided Spreadsheet. If you use different values and an error occurs, it is required to prepare another script by modifying the script. In this case, please post it as a new question. By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @user8702720 About your 2nd question of `Also, the script is missing the last paragraphs of the article in the last column where we summarize all lines after the tag of "H2" is existing 6 times.`, when I tested your initial Spreadsheet, I think that your issue was resolved. If you change the values and an issue occurs, please post it as a new question. By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @user8702720 About your 2nd question, if the error occurs using your initial Spreadsheet, please tell me. I would like to modify the script. By the way, when you post your new question, please include your sample input and output values you expect. And, if you have other patterns of sample input values that you have never shown, please include them in the new question. First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Can you please fix the `Also, the script is missing the last paragraphs of the article in the last column where we summarize all lines after the tag of "H2" is existing 6 times.` this issue in the above script? and For the error, I will post a new question. Again Thank you so much. Really appreciate your help. Please help me to fix this issue. Trying to solve this in quite a few days, please. Thank you

Comment: @user8702720 Thank you for replying. About `Also, the script is missing the last paragraphs of the article in the last column where we summarize all lines after the tag of "H2" is existing 6 times.`, when I tested your initial sample Spreadsheet, I think that your expected result is achieved. So, I'm worried whether I could correctly understand your initial question. If I misunderstood your initial question, please tell me. I would like to modify it. Can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including your initial Spreadsheet and your sample input and output values again?

Comment: @user8702720 About `For the error, I will post a new question.`, when I saw your new question, I would like to check it.

Comment: @user8702720 Now, I confirmed your initial Spreadsheet. When my script is used for your value, I can confirm that your "Output I want" can be obtained. So, I cannot understand `Also, the script is missing the last paragraphs of the article in the last column where we summarize all lines after the tag of "H2" is existing 6 times.`. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. But, I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @user8702720 Unfortunately, when I tested my script to your initial Spreadsheet, I can confirm that "Output I want" is obtained from your value. I deeply apologize for this situation. If your "Output I want" is not your expected result, I think that I misunderstood your expected result. At that time, it is required to know your actual expected result. I'm confused about your questions. I apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Can you please test your script on this attached spreadsheet. [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FzWmcXQRyu25V4mdXQPVvafX4X5sUUODzEJ4xUywVPc/edit#gid=0) is the spreadsheet in which I have added the articles. Please check. Thank you

Comment: You will see that the Last paragraphs of each article are missing in the last column. Only <h2>Conclusion</h2> at the end. Paragraphs those are beneath <h2>Conclusion</h2> are missing. thank you so much

Comment: @user8702720 Thank you for providing the sample Spreadsheet. When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, it seems that it is different from your initial sample Spreadsheet. In your initial Spreadsheet, the 1st line is `<h1>First H1</h1>`.And,  I'm worried that the reason for your issue of `Also, the script is missing the last paragraphs of the article in the last column where we summarize all lines after the tag of "H2" is existing 6 times.` might be due to that you changed your Spreadsheet.

Comment: @user8702720 I confirm your initial spreadsheet again. Unfortunately, `Here` of `Can you please test your script on this attached spreadsheet? Here is the spreadsheet in which I have added the articles.` is different from your initial one. If you want to change your Spreadsheet, please post it as a new question. And, please test my script using your initial spreadsheet again. I would like to recommend resolving your questions in order. I would like to support you. But, if you change the sample after I posted my answer using your initial sample, I'm confused. I apologize for this.

Comment: @user8702720 If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @user8702720 I noticed that you had posted your new question of https://stackoverflow.com/q/75712754 . In this case, how will you do this question?

Comment: Thank you so much. You asked me to post a new question. That's why I have posted a new question.

Comment: I will accept your this answer. Please do answer that question. So, I can get the proper solution. Thank you so much

Comment: @user8702720 Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood my proposed script resolved your initial question. Is my understanding correct?