# Divided HTML tags of an article into separate columns using App script in Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using the App Script, I need to break down the article:

In the first column, this one would be whatever the `<h1>` is, in the second column whatever the first `<h2>` is, in the next column all the paragraphs `<p>` are going underneath it, then in the next whatever the second `<h2>` is, all the paragraphs `<p>` are going underneath that one and so on up until it gets to the seventh `<h2>` and the article still remains. And then at that point, I wanted just to dump the rest of the article into the last column. So, like for an article where we may have multiple `<h2>` more than seven, it would just put all remaining article in that last column.

I am using the below app script code to get the job done.
But **this code has two issues.**

First, this code doesn't dump the last paragraphs `<p>` tags that come after the last `<h2>` (`<h2>`Conclusion`</h2>`) of an article into the last column.

Second, the script gives this error on some articles.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'match')
(anonymous) @ Code.gs:44
(anonymous) @ Code.gs:43
myFunction  @ Code.gs:41
```

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MZQHHD0s5pdA2rYWNUjXIG1BQ3UdzYpbEop7R-HqqGA/edit#gid=0) is the spreadsheet link which has the articles and the app script. In Row 3, What I want as output. In Row 4, what the script gives is output. The only difference between Row 3 and Row 4 is that Row 4 doesn't have the last paragraphs `<p>` tags that come after the last `<h2>` (`<h2>`Conclusion`</h2>`) of an article in the last column.

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pasteSheet = [ {name: "Run Script", functionName: "myFunction"}];
  ss.addMenu("Break Down Article", pasteSheet);
}

function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const temp1 = range.getValues().map(([a]) =>
    a.split("\n").reduce((o, e, i, a) => {
      if (e) {
        let tagMatch = e.match(/^<(.*?)>/);
        let tag = tagMatch ? tagMatch[1].toUpperCase() : "";
        if (tag != "P") {
          if (o.temp.length > 0) {
            o.res.push(o.temp);
            o.temp = [];
          }
          o.res.push([e]);
        } else if (i == a.length - 1) {
          if (tag == "P") {
            o.temp.push(e);
            o.res.push(o.temp);
          } else {
            o.res.push([e]);
          }
        } else {
          o.temp.push(e);
        }
      }
      return o;
    }, { res: [], temp: [] }).res
  ).map(e => e.map(f => f.join("\n")));
  const maxLen = Math.max(...temp1.map(r => r.length));

  // I modified below script.
  const values = temp1.map(r => [...r, ...Array(maxLen - r.length).fill(null)]);
  const res = values.map(r => {
    let n = 0;
    const idx = r.map(e => {
      let tagMatch = e.match(/^<(.*?)>/);
      let tag = tagMatch ? tagMatch[1].toUpperCase() : "";
      return tag && tag.includes("H2") ? ++n : 0;
    }).indexOf(7);
    return [...r.splice(0, idx), r.join("\n")];
  });
  range.offset(0, 2, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

Comment: I have a question. In your question, your sample values are 5 values in your provided Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct? If you have other sample values, please include them. And, in order to correctly understand your expected result, can you provide your expected output values? First, I would like to correctly understand your question. I apologize for this.

Comment: Yes, I have 5 sample values. That's all for now. I don't have any other. Thank you so much

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script for your sample values. Please confirm it.

Comment: Now, I modified the script. Please test it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your provided sample Spreadsheet, how about the following sample script?

From your sample values, I moved the adjustment of the length of each element in a 2-dimensional array after the array processing. And, I added a condition for checking the value from `e.match(/^<(.*?)>/)`.

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("A3:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const temp1 = range.getValues().map(([a]) =>
    a.split("\n").reduce((o, e, i, a) => {
      let m = e.match(/^<(.*?)>/);
      let tag = "";
      if (m) {
        tag = m[1].toUpperCase();
      }
      if (tag != "P") {
        if (o.temp.length > 0) {
          o.res.push(o.temp);
          o.temp = [];
        }
        o.res.push([e]);
      } else if (i == a.length - 1) {
        if (tag == "P") {
          o.temp.push(e);
          o.res.push(o.temp);
        } else {
          o.res.push([e]);
        }
      } else {
        o.temp.push(e);
      }
      return o;
    }, { res: [], temp: [] }).res
  ).map(e => e.map(f => f.join("\n")));
  const res = temp1.map(r => {
    let n = 0;
    const idx = r.map(e => e ? (e.toUpperCase().includes("H2") ? ++n : 0) : 0).indexOf(7);
    return [...r.splice(0, idx > -1 ? idx : r.length), r.join("\n").trim()];
  });
  const maxLen = Math.max(...res.map(r => r.length));
  const values = res.map(r => [...r, ...Array(maxLen - r.length).fill(null)]);
  range.offset(0, 2, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Note:

- From `I have 5 sample values. That's all for now. I don't have any other.`, this sample script is for your 5 sample values. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Thank you so much. Still, there is an issue that I faced. Hopefully, this would be the last one. Really sorry to bother you again and again. [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MZQHHD0s5pdA2rYWNUjXIG1BQ3UdzYpbEop7R-HqqGA/edit#gid=0) spreadsheet in which I add an article for which script is not working as expected. Please please adjust that article in the script. Again really sorry for that. I missed that.

Comment: @user8702720 Thank you for replying. When I asked `In your question, your sample values are 5 values in your provided Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct?`, you said `Yes, I have 5 sample values. That's all for now. I don't have any other.`. So, about your reply, this is a new question. And, your added value is different from your initial 5 values. In this case, it is required to change the specification of your question. So, please post it as a new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @user8702720 And, from your reply, I cannot still know whether my answer resolved your 5 values. Please don't change your question after I posted an answer. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have posted a new question as you asked. Please do help with that. Really sorry, I missed the 6th article last time.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75739082/fix-breakdown-of-html-tags-using-app-script-in-google-sheet) is link of it. Thank you so much