# Fix breakdown of HTML tags using App Script in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using the App Script, I need to break down the article:

In the first column, this one would be whatever the `<h1>` is, in the second column whatever the first `<h2>` is, in the next column all the paragraphs `<p>` are going underneath it, then in the next whatever the second `<h2>` is, all the paragraphs `<p>` are going underneath that one and so on up until it gets to the seventh `<h2>` and the article still remains. And then at that point, I wanted just to dump the rest of the article into the last column. So, like for an article where we may have multiple `<h2>` more than seven, it would just put all remaining article in that last column.

I am using the below app script code to get the job done.
But **this code has one issue.**

Only the article in last row isn't not working as expected due to extra HTML tags (Highlighted ones). These extra HTML tags should be put in `<p>` tags columns. As there are part of `<p>` tags.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MZQHHD0s5pdA2rYWNUjXIG1BQ3UdzYpbEop7R-HqqGA/edit#gid=0) is the spreadsheet link which has the articles and the app script.
[image]

```
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("A3:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const temp1 = range.getValues().map(([a]) =>
    a.split("\n").reduce((o, e, i, a) => {
      let m = e.match(/^<(.*?)>/);
      let tag = "";
      if (m) {
        tag = m[1].toUpperCase();
      }
      if (tag != "P") {
        if (o.temp.length > 0) {
          o.res.push(o.temp);
          o.temp = [];
        }
        o.res.push([e]);
      } else if (i == a.length - 1) {
        if (tag == "P") {
          o.temp.push(e);
          o.res.push(o.temp);
        } else {
          o.res.push([e]);
        }
      } else {
        o.temp.push(e);
      }
      return o;
    }, { res: [], temp: [] }).res
  ).map(e => e.map(f => f.join("\n")));
  const res = temp1.map(r => {
    let n = 0;
    const idx = r.map(e => e ? (e.toUpperCase().includes("H2") ? ++n : 0) : 0).indexOf(7);
    return [...r.splice(0, idx > -1 ? idx : r.length), r.join("\n").trim()];
  });
  const maxLen = Math.max(...res.map(r => r.length));
  const values = res.map(r => [...r, ...Array(maxLen - r.length).fill(null)]);
  range.offset(0, 2, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample output value using your sample input value? Because I cannot know your expected result from your question. I apologize for this. By the way, in your this question, there are only 6 sample values in your sample Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, I have added the sample output value for the sample input value in attached spreadsheet. I have highlighted the sample output value in green color. Highlighted in yellow color is what the script gives as output.  Thank you

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your expected result, I could test the script. I proposed a sample script. Please confirm it. This script is for your sample value. Please be careful about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("A3:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const tags = ["P", "OL", "LI", "UL"].flatMap(e => [e, `/${e}`]); // Added
  const temp1 = range.getValues().map(([a]) =>
    a.split("\n").reduce((o, e, i, a) => {
      let m = e.match(/^<(.*?)>/);
      let tag = "";
      if (m) {
        tag = m[1].toUpperCase();
      }
      if (!tags.includes(tag)) { // Modified
        if (o.temp.length > 0) {
          o.res.push(o.temp);
          o.temp = [];
        }
        o.res.push([e]);
      } else if (i == a.length - 1) {
        if (tags.includes(tag)) { // Modified
          o.temp.push(e);
          o.res.push(o.temp);
        } else {
          o.res.push([e]);
        }
      } else {
        o.temp.push(e);
      }
      return o;
    }, { res: [], temp: [] }).res
  ).map(e => e.map(f => f.join("\n")));
  const res = temp1.map(r => {
    let n = 0;
    const idx = r.map(e => e ? (e.toUpperCase().includes("H2") ? ++n : 0) : 0).indexOf(7);
    return [...r.splice(0, idx > -1 ? idx : r.length), r.join("\n").trim()];
  });
  const maxLen = Math.max(...res.map(r => r.length));
  const values = res.map(r => [...r, ...Array(maxLen - r.length).fill(null)]);
  range.offset(0, 2, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Note:

- This is for your sample value. So, when you change the value and Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.